# Calculate the sum of differences of all rows in pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a non-manual way of finding the absolute neighbouring distance between all data in all columns.

Currently, I am doing this manually:

```
dataset['Delta'] =   (
        abs(dataset.iloc[:,0] - dataset.iloc[:,1]) +
        abs(dataset.iloc[:,1] - dataset.iloc[:,2]) 
                     )
```

[image]

But I need to work with much bigger dataFrames containing 100s of columns. Need help with automation.

Comment: Step 1: `dataset.shape` gives you the number of columns. Step 2: From there, write a for-loop using `range`. Step 3: Profit

Comment: okay, I see. Thanks. Do you think there may be a solution of this sort (such as summing across): df['e'] = df.sum(axis=1)

Comment: that's a good idea. But that might require calculating the intermediate `abs(...)` as other columns to then be `.drop`'d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Delta'] = df.diff(axis=1).abs().sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         0        1        2    Delta
0  300.087  300.127  300.086    0.081
1  300.087  300.127  300.086    0.081
2  200.088  300.127  300.087  100.079
3  200.088  300.127  300.088  100.078
4  300.089  300.127  300.089    0.076
5  300.089  300.127  300.090    0.075
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
In [691]: import numpy as np

In [692]: df['Delta'] = np.abs(np.diff(df.values, axis=1)).sum(1) 

In [694]: df
Out[694]: 
         0        1        2  Delta
0  300.087  300.127  300.086  0.081
1  300.087  300.127  300.086  0.081
2  300.088  300.127  300.087  0.079
3  300.088  300.127  300.088  0.078
```